# Trying to animate vexflow JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am following these https://github.com/0xfe/vexflow/wiki/Animation-with-VexFlow-&-CSS instructions. I have copied the configuration verbatum, but error occurs: SVGConext is not defined. I have vexflow-debug.js included as a script. I'm not entirely sure if it defines SVGConent but it seems to. Anyway, I include svgcontent.js which seems sensible but it returns werror: Unspected token input.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it by going back and reentering everything. Sorry about that but I guess you get that a lot?

If it breaks again, I'll spend more time on my side.

Ian